# How to indent 4 spaces under SGML mode

Tags: emacs

You know under SGML mode (PSGML) Emacs could indent the XML buffer automatically.

```
C-x-h ;; Select all
M-C-\ ;; Indent
```

But all the indent was 2 spaces. How can I set to make auto indent to 4 spaces?

I tried `(setq-default sgml-indent-step 4)`, but it doesn't work.

Current view is:

```
<TESTCASE>
  <NAME>00001<NAME>
  <TIMEOUT>600000</TIMEOUT>
```

My expectation is

```
<TESTCASE>
    <NAME>00001<NAME>
    <TIMEOUT>600000</TIMEOUT>
```

Thanks!

Using GNU Emacs 22.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600)
of 2008-03-26 on RELEASE

Comment: Not a duplicate, but you may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934/set-4-space-indent-in-emacs-in-text-mode informative.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for `sgml-basic-offset`

Edit: Actually, I should add how I figured that out. No one should understate the power that a self-documented editor provides:

Open an sgml document

`C-h k tab` says it's bound to a function that looks at variable `indent-line-function`.

`C-h v indent-line-function` told me to look at function `sgml-indent-line`

`C-h f sgml-indent-line` told me very little. Nothing really. But it also provided where it was implemented.

Well, looking at the implementation, I found that it's using `sgml-calculate-indent`. That's the meat of the algorithm... Go down and you can find the `tag` case, where the last element does

`(+ (current-column) sgml-basic-offset)`

A quick `C-h v sgml-basic-offset` will make sure we're looking at the one variable that is supposed to be customized. It indeed is.

Comment: Thanks! You told me not only answers, but also methods. 
It's an very effective way to follow for any issues on Emacs! 
I tried, and it works. Thanks! 
(setq sgml-basic-offset 4)

Comment: How `C-h v indent-line-function` told you to look at `sgml-indent-line`? I can't follow that indirection.

Comment: Mmm... and it does not work for me. I think this is an old post.

Comment: @nephewtom: not sure why I missed your comment 4 years ago, but if you do C-h v indent-line-function _while in a buffer that is in sgml-mode_ it will tell you that the value of that variable is sgml-indent-line. I just tried changing the value of sgml-basic-offset again, and it still works.

Comment: Ha, ha, ha! It has been a long time! It seems at that time I switched to use nxml mode.
I even asked and answer my own question, similar to this one:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/how-to-set-indent-to-4-spaces-in-nxml-mode

Comment: By the way, I just changed to sgml-mode and could follow your explanations.
Though I am not that smart (or I'd say I am too lazy to understand `sgml-calculate-indent` algorithm), but I get how you arrived to that. Anyway, it seems I am currently using nxml when I edit XML on Emacs.

Comment: yup, I am also using nxml!