# Emacs indentation in Asm mode

Tags: emacs, indentation

I am looking for the equivalent of `c-indent-level` and `ruby-indent-level`, for `asm-mode`. That is, I want to force the indentation to 4 spaces, and I want them to be replaced with blanks.

What I've seen tells me it does not exist for asm-mode. Could someone please tell me this is wrong?

I tried this also: [Set 4 Space Indent in Emacs in Text Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934/set-4-space-indent-in-emacs-in-text-mode) , to no av.

I have tried:

```
(setq tab-width 4)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
(setq asm-indent-level 4)
```

This works however:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(tab-stop-list (quote (4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 68 72 76 80 84 88 92 96 100 104 108 112 116 120))))
```

But I wonder if there is a way to define that for `asm-mode` only. What if I wanted to keep the default tab behaviour for other modes?

Answer (score 3):

asm-mode uses the function tab-to-tab-stop for [indentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Asm-Mode.html), that's why tab-stop-list is working. As far I know there is nothing more that you can do. You might consider using some of the "more advanced" asm modes such as - [gas-mode](http://www.hczim.de/software/gas-mode.html) or [asm86-mode](http://wolverine.caltech.edu/tools/emacs86/).

Answer (score -1):

Emacs defines hooks for every (?) major mode. If you do H-m in assembly file, you can see at the end of text section that Assembler mode hook is called `asm-mode-hook'. So you can add your code to run when assembler mode is selected for a buffer like this:

```
(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook (lambda()
                           (setq tab-width 4)
                           (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
                           (setq asm-indent-level 4)))
```

Note, tab-width and indent-line-function are already buffer local variables, so setting them changes their value only for the current buffer. This is probably what you want. If you setq some other variables, you may want to make them buffer local using (make-variable-buffer-local VARIABLE) function.