# make emacs use real tab character for indentation with every language

Tags: emacs

I want to make emacs use real tabs for indentation for every language, and want the tab to be approximately 4 spaces in width (but to be a real tab, as in vim).
I tries in .emacs :

```
(setq tab-width 4)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
```

Nothing happens : emacs continue to indent by 2 spaces in C/C++, and a tab ob length 8 in Python!

Comment: I think, that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934/set-4-space-indent-in-emacs-in-text-mode should explain this

Answer (score 3):

`c-mode` overrides quite a bit of Emacs default behaviour, including indentation. You may read more on it here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Indentation-Engine-Basics .
Which means that you probably want to set `c-syntactic-indentation` to `nil` to loose all the goodies of `c-mode` indentation (which can insert arbitrary number of spaces regardless of other Emacs settings).

Perhaps, your other approach could be to tinker `c-mode` specifically to behave as you'd like it to. In which case this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC#toc3 should help.

PS. I almost don't write in C, so I don't know how much good/bad will that be w/o the default behaviour. I'm happy with using spaces always, and never tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `tab-width` does not change the amount of columns programming language modes use to indent the code. This value just indicates how many space characters it takes to convert to one tab, and how to display a tab character.

The indentation offset in columns is set per-language. For C, for example, set `c-basic-offset` to 4. For Python, set `python-indent-offset`. It's already 4 by default, though.

Aside from that, you might want to replace `(setq tab-width 4)` with `(setq-default tab-width 4)`. This is also a buffer-local variable.