# how to control tabs and whitespace with emacs version 24.3?

Tags: emacs, tabs

I am unable to get emacs version 24.3 to indent two whitespaces when I hit the tab key in fundamental mode. I've read a number of other posts, such as [set 4 Space Indent in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934/set-4-space-indent-in-emacs-in-text-mode).  I'm pretty sure this used to work in older emacs versions:

```
(setq tab-width 2)
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

I'm now trying all this:

```
(setq tab-width 2)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 2 400 2))
```

Now I find that tab is indenting to go right after the first white space block in the line

```
this is my first line
     second line starts here
```

I can't figure out how to get it to simple to

```
this is my first line
  second line starts here
```

Maybe the problem is my configuration?  I have installed this new version of emacs in my own user home directory - it is not system wide version of emacs.

Comment: I think the fundamental-mode-hook is broken -- this should have worked, but it doesn't -- sorry:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934/set-4-space-indent-in-emacs-in-text-mode

Comment: Fundamental mode inherits text-mode hooks . . . hmmm.

Comment: lawlist: `fundamental-mode-hook` isn't broken; it (intentionally) doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah . . . that explains it -- thank you.  Is the only option then to manually call the function setting tab sets after entering fundamental mode?

Comment: You could use `after-change-major-mode-hook` which will be run. e.g. `(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook (lambda () (when (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode) ...)))`

Comment: Yes, that works -- thank you -- I learned something new.  But now I feel too guilty to post an answer.  The credit goes to `phils`  :)

Comment: Ah, except that hook isn't called unless you are actually changing from another mode, so it won't run when you simply create a new buffer. That makes things trickier. Maybe a good question at this point is "why do you want to customise fundamental mode?". Whatever the reason, there's probably a better approach using a custom mode.

Comment: We'll leave that to the O.P. to give us some additional input . . . . I just wanted to help solve the problem and learn something in the process . . . .  I have a text-mode-hook and a LaTeX-mode-hook setting tabs to 5 spaces, which text-mode-hook is inherited by fundamental mode, but which can be overridden using the after-change-mode-hook by phils.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your "I'm now trying all this" config works just fine:

```el
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 2 400 2))
```

If you reduce your init file to this, it should work as desired.

You may be clobbering the settings elsewhere in your config?

Comment: That is working - in fact my whole .emacs file is working now.  What I was doing to test this was

Comment: That is working - in fact my whole .emacs file is working now.  What I was doing to test this was emacs -Q to bypass my .emacs file, and then creating a small file jnk.el with a few of the commands in it.  If jnk.el is the above commands and I run M-x eval-buffer on it, then it does not work.  If I run M-x load-file on jnk.el, it doesn't work.  But if My current buffer is my text file (in fundamental mode) and I do M-x load-file on jnk.el, then the commands in jnk.el DO start applying to text file!  Is this unexpected?  Thanks for the help, I'm past this frustration now.

Comment: I suspect you're just getting confused by pre-existing buffer-local values. The above commands will set defaults (as the first two vars are automatically buffer-local, but the second two are not), but if you are evaluating/loading the code after starting Emacs, existing buffers will already have their own local values.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do if you want to change the behavior "when I hit " is to do `C-h k <foo>`.  That will tell you which command is run, and might give you some further hints about how to change its behavior.  The behavior of the TAB key depends on the major mode, so making it do what you want depends on the major mode you're using.  If you're using `fundamental-mode`, you'renot using Emacs in the normal way, so I'd recommend you try and fix that first.