# Why does emacs display tabs differently?

Tags: emacs, whitespace, highlight, indentation

So I've heard about the goodness of emacs and have only recently started using it. Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but why does emacs display tabs, differently? It seems as though it doubles the number of spaces, but it doesn't, at least, I guess. Here're some pictures to describe what I'm talking about:

[image]

And this is what it looks like in emacs:

[image]

As I've previously stated, it seems as though it doubles the number of spaces. When I add this line to .emacs:

```
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
```

and reindenting the code using C-x h C-M-\ makes it look normal in emacs, but the secondary indentation are in-line with the first indentation (as in 2 tabs are now 1 tab) when viewed in other text editors, and again, I couldn't understand why. Changing it to

```
(setq c-basic-offset 8)
```

makes it save and display normally in other text editors though. At this point I'm really, really confused.

Can someone please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: I keep clicking on this thinking it will be about why are Emacs *file* tabs different from Vims. (In the long tradition of folks trying to get one to behave like the other.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `tab-width` is the distance between tab spaces in columns, and defaults to 8.  If you'd like it to default to 4, you can `(setq-default tab-width 4)`.  If you'd like to untabify everything and convert tabs to spaces, you can do `M-: (untabify (point-min) (point-max))`.

And you might find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934/set-4-space-indent-in-emacs-in-text-mode) helpful, especially the point on `tab-stop-list` when you want to ADD your own tabs.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I just realised I mixed up setq and setq-default as I mistakenly typed only setq when copying from EmacsWiki. Does this only apply to c-mode though? Thanks again!

Comment: It applies to any buffer that uses tabs.  If you really want to, you could have different tab widths for each buffer.  For more information, try `C-h v tab-width`.

Comment: Is there a c-mode specific option?

Comment: Do you mean setting a specific value only in c-mode?  You could do `(defun my-c-hook () (setq tab-width 4))` and then `(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-hook)` to have 4-column tabs only in c-mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can also adopt sanity and not use TAB chars in your code. ;-)

To **prevent inserting** TAB chars when you hit the `TAB` key (and `RET` or `C-j`, depending on your Emacs version) set the value of option **`indent-tabs-mode`** to `nil`.

To remove pre-existing TAB chars from code you are editing, use command **`untabify`**.

See also [Tabs Are Evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/TabsAreEvil) and [Untabify Upon Save](http://www.emacswiki.org/UntabifyUponSave).

And note that, in Emacs, whether or not you use TAB chars is unrelated to how much and whether code is indented.  For example, option `c-basic-offset` governs indentation amount regardless of whether TABs are used for some of the indenting.

Note too that after you kick the TAB habit, any TAB chars left in your code that are meaningful to the code are much easier to find. They are not lost in an ocean of insignificant-whitespace TABs.

Finally, note that there are various ways to highlight TAB chars.  Command `hc-toggle-highlight-tabs` in library [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight-chars.el) is one way.  See [Show Whitespace](http://www.emacswiki.org/ShowWhiteSpace).

Comment: Didn't know using tabs is bad :O

It's just that I've been using using Sublime Text all this while and it inserts tab automatically by default when I press Return, and it never bothered me before. Thanks for enlightening me! It's a shame that I still can't upvote yet. I don't really get your last part though. Sorry I'm still kinda new to this.

Comment: Sorry I can't edit my comment anymore. I meant I didn't understand the part on c-basic-offset.

Comment: It's not that using TAB chars is bad. It's that some of us prefer not to use them. Some people prefer to use them. That's why Emacs has an option, `indent-tabs-mode`, to let you decide.

Comment: The point about `c-basic-offset` was that whether you use (a) TAB chars plus SPC chars or (b) only SPC chars for indentation, the visual result of indenting is the same: code is indented to the same columns etc. And since, in Emacs, hitting `TAB` (or `RET` or `C-j`, depending) indents to the proper column (regardless of which whitespace chars are used to do that), the argument that using TAB chars means fewer key presses than using SPC chars disappears.