# How can I set tabwidth and insert space for typescript mode?

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs on Windows. Can you please how can I set tabwidth and insert space for TypeScript mode?  I want the TypeScript file setting and Java file setting are different.

Thank you.

Comment: The `README.md` file for `typescript.el` states:  "*To customize typescript.el just type the following: `M-x customize-group<RET>typescript<RET>`.  You can add any other customization you like to typescript-mode-hook in your init.el file. typescript.el also handles prog-mode-hook on versions of Emacs which supports it.*"  [ https://github.com/ananthakumaran/typescript.el ] Have you googled how to set the `tab-width` for a major-mode?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127986/2112489  What is "insert space"?

Comment: I have tried that. But how can I make it converts TAB to SPACE? in typescript mode?

Comment: If you want to actually modify the buffer when it loads (by untabifying everything), see this blog:  http://blog.modelworks.ch/get-rid-of-tabs-in-emacs/