# emacs: Want to indent with tabs (tab-size 2 or 4) allign with spaces

Tags: emacs, tabs, indentation, spaces, tab-size

I use emacs now for a while and like it in most cases (useful on ssh, syntax highlight, ...).

But when it comes to indentation and justification (alignment) of code, I don't get clear with emacs.

I want in **all my code** (SQL, C, Java, ECMAScript, HTML, PHP, CSS, ...) that a press of the "TAB" key realy makes a TAB character (which I usually have a size of 2 spaces, but 4 or 6 are good as well). [I agree, that TABs in Code are evil when it comes to alignment, but spaces are evil as well, when it comes to indentation!] You can have a look, how I want to have it in my HTML template:
[https://github.com/pheek/HTMLTemplate/blob/master/*template*.html](https://github.com/pheek/HTMLTemplate/blob/master/_template_.html)

On the other hand I always align with spaces, so other programmers have all the equal signs properly aligned in my code. This works fine, except for 2 exceptions:

1. To enter a TAB-Char I always have to press "CTRL-q TAB", which is annoying.
2. Different programming languages are configured in emacs to use different TAB sizes. For myself, I always want to behave a TAB to be the size of 2 spaces.

How can I achieve that

a) a press of the TAB-Key always inserts a TAB-Char?

b) TABs are in all emacs-modes (c, java, html, php, css, ecmascript, ...) 2 chars wide?

Comment: `C-q TAB` will insert a tab.  Every major-mode *can* set these things differently, and some have their own variables that need to be customized to achieve the desired result.  Thus, focus on setting up just one major-mode and then move on to the next until satisfied.  Here is a link to an example to get you started:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17563/trouble-adjusting-tab-width  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69934/set-4-space-indent-in-emacs-in-text-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @lawlist says, it's different for every major mode.  Each one usually has its own `indent-line-function`, and settings like `tab-width` are buffer local.

There's a `smart-tabs` package (https://github.com/jcsalomon/smarttabs) that works well for me, but I only use it for C-like modes (which is not to say it doesn't work for others, I just haven't tried).

```
(use-package smart-tabs-mode
  :commands (smart-tabs-mode)
  :init
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook #'smart-tabs-mode)
  :config
  (smart-tabs-advice c-indent-line     c-basic-offset)
  (smart-tabs-advice c-indent-region   c-basic-offset)
  )
```

`tab-width` should be set to your preferred width globally, and can be changed in major mode hooks to be different in some modes.

```
(setq-default tab-width 2)

(defun jpk/c-mode-common-hook ()
   (setq tab-width 4))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook #'jpk/c-mode-common-hook)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen "smart-tabs-mode" before and now downloaded "smart-tabs-mode.el" and load this from my configuration file. Unfortunately your above mentioned code (especially "use-package") does not work. I get the message: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function use-package)`. What to do, to be able to use the "use-package" command?

Comment: I finally got it to work using "smart-tabs-mode.el". I don't use your `use-package` code, but simply load `smart-tabs-mode.el` and then run the insinuate code : `(smart-tabs-insinuate 'c 'c++ 'java 'javascript 'cperl 'python 'ruby 'nxml)`. Works!

Comment: @iGeeks `use-package` is a popular way to install and configure packages, but it is not built in.  I was lazy and just pasted my config instead of translating it to built in commands.

Answer (score 2):

a) Set the value of `indent-tabs-mode` to non-nil in your emacs configuration file.
`(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)` should do the trick.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation.html

b) Similarly, set the value of `tab-width` to the desired width.
`(setq-default tab-width 2)` in your case.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Changing-the-length-of-a-Tab.html

Comment: I had already both "setq-default"s in my config file. Seams, that some major modes override my behavior. But thanks for the links.